# Determination of Control on which text will be dropped

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array, drag-and-drop

I've created an array of labels on a form as follows::

```
Private Sub CreateArray()
    ReDim lblArray(mRowCount, mColumnCount)

    Try
        Dim xDistance As Integer
        Dim yDistance As Integer

        xDistance = mFormWidth / mColumnCount
        yDistance = mFormHeight / mRowCount

        Dim iRow As Integer = 0
        Dim iCol As Integer = 0
        Dim RowPosition As Integer
        Dim ColumnPosition As Integer
        For iRow = 0 To mRowCount - 1
            RowPosition = xArray + (xDistance * iRow)
            'Increment through rows
            iCol = 0
            For iCol = 0 To mColumnCount - 1
                lblArray(iRow, iCol) = New Label()
                ColumnPosition = yArray + (mFormHeight - (yDistance * (iCol + 1)))

                'Increment through columns
                With lblArray(iRow, iCol)
                    .AutoSize = False
                    .Location = New Point(RowPosition, ColumnPosition)
                    .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(xDistance, yDistance)
                    .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                    .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
                    .Text = "(" & iRow & ", " & iCol & ")"
                    If iRow = 0 And iCol = 0 Then
                        .BackColor = hexToRbgNew(mPivotColor)
                    ElseIf iRow = 0 Or iCol = 0 Then
                        .BackColor = hexToRbgNew(mAxisColor)
                        .AllowDrop = False
                    Else
                        .BackColor = hexToRbgNew(mCellColor)
                        .AllowDrop = True
                    End If
                    AddHandler .Click, AddressOf lblArray_Click
                    AddHandler .DragDrop, AddressOf lblArray_DragDrop
                    AddHandler .DragEnter, AddressOf lblArray_DragEnter
                    Me.Controls.Add(lblArray(iRow, iCol))
                End With
            Next
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

To drop text to change the current text of a designated label, I need to know the name of the control that I intend to act upon. I thought GetChildAtPoint would serve the purpose but have been unable to determine the specific label on which to act (i.e., the label under the current mouse position). How can I determine the specific label? I want to change the text of the specific label and the tag on that label based on the information I'm pulling from a listbox (a unique id->label.tag, and displayed text->label.text. Web searches have resulted in no specific approach for determining which label is to be acted upon.

May not be the most efficient approach (open to suggestions) to accomplish the need. Basic attempt is to create an array with an x and y axis and then to populate the cells of the matrix with values dragged from a listbox of values and unique ids.

Comment: The sender object in the Drop event, cast to a Label control as needed.

Comment: Thank you. I've resolved my issue.